# useEffect hook wont run codeblock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My useEffect hook dont seem to be running the block of code within its scope. Not exactly sure why, when i debug it the useEffect hook gets hit but the code within it never runs. I have placed a break point and it never lands on it.

```
    import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const useApiResult = (request) => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData(request);
    }, [request]); 

    const loadData = async (request) => {
        console.log(request)
        try 
        {
            const response = await fetch(request);
            if(response.ok) {
                setResults(await response.json());
                setError(null);
            } else {
                setError(await response.text());
            } 
        } 
        catch (err) {
            setError(err);
        } 
    }
  
  return [results, error];
};

export default useApiResult;
```

Where I call useApiResult

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { getPokemons } from '../requests';
import useApiResult  from '../customHooks/useApiResults';

const usePokemons = () => {
    const request = useMemo(() => getPokemons(), []);
    return useApiResult(request);
}

export default usePokemons;
```

getpokemons.js

```
export const BASE_URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2";

const createUrl = (base, path) => `${base}${path}`;

export const getPokemons = () => [
  createUrl(BASE_URL, "/pokemon?offset=300&limit=10"),
  {
    method: "GET",
  }
];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pls show us where and how you are using `useApiResult`. Because You are using `, [request]` dependency.

Comment: Your code seems to be completely valid, all by the book. I bet the reason lays somewhere outside of it. Please check that your webpack has indeed re-generated the bundle (check the bundle and find this code there), maybe it's just hitting the breakpoint using old source map. Also check that there aren't any other errors (break on unhandled errors) - could be that after promise returns something else fails and promise is never resolved; and maybe check in different browser (Chrome?)

Comment: I have added more code to depict the flow of data. Will check in chrome i like that idea

Comment: does your network tab show that the request is being made?

Comment: Nope it never gets made

Answer (score 1):

**My steps to catch issue:**

1. When I looked in your sandbox I noticed error: `results is null`
2. I also found `const [results, error] = usePokemons();` in `PokemonList`  component, so I thought that this `error` is not necessary, I just removed it. Because you never used it in component.
3. I still got `results is null` I just add `condition render` via `&&`. It looks like:

   ```
        results &&
          results.map((key, i) => (
   ```
4. I got new error: `results.map is not a function`. It means that results is not `array`. When I saw at  `results` I noticed that it has inside array with the same `name`. So I just add `resuts` after a dot.

   ```
    results &&
      results.results.map((key, i) => (
   ```

Here we go:)

Comment: Nope, `request` just a simple param. In terms of meaning, it should be `url` naming.

Comment: ok, try to convert it to state. I think that useEffect dependecy call effect only when react can detect changes.

Comment: I see. But I also not sure that useEffect can be used outside react component

Comment: can you make sandbox for playing with your issue?

Comment: Of course, but it depends on `Where OP call useApiResult` using `useMemo` as well.

Comment: useEffect is a function called from under the hood of react

Comment: try to make sandbox and I'll try to help you as soon as possible, and please, use a minimum of code))

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-kare-dic8u?file=/src/components/PokemonList.js

Comment: well, but I need also represent issue in it. did you save files?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-kare-dic8u?file=/src/customHooks/useApiResults.js  now try ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-field-ikhgk?file=/src/components/PokemonList.js

Comment: I'll add explain in my answer